# Display also null values when using WHERE in JOIN clause

Tags: sql

Need help with following SQL query. I have a list with clients and progress of each person is stored in validation table. I need to use following statement inside a cursor and use also the `record_id` to fetch for that exact day but it will return only the clients and number of hours for the existing values. Used `LEFT JOIN`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN` . without the WHERE clause works perfectly but i will fetch mixed results and won't help.

```
SELECT 
    CLI.id client_id
   ,CLI.name client_name
   ,VLD.number_of_hours number_of_hours 
FROM 
   client CLI 
LEFT JOIN 
   validation VLD 
ON 
   CLI.id = VLD.client_id
WHERE 
   VLD.record_id = 392;
```

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Your `WHERE` is forcing your `LEFT JOIN` to be a `INNER JOIN`. Move your record id filter as another condition for your left join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the right side table condition from `WHERE` to `ON` to get true `LEFT JOIN` result.

```
SELECT 
    CLI.id client_id
   ,CLI.name client_name
   ,VLD.number_of_hours number_of_hours 
FROM 
   client CLI 
LEFT JOIN 
   validation VLD 
ON 
   CLI.id = VLD.client_id
AND
   VLD.record_id = 392;
```

(When in WHERE, the left join returns regular inner join result.)

Comment: Thank you very much ! This works perfectly . Didn't thought this way . Now I understand. Thank you.